# Formatted output in C based on end condition

Tags: c, loops, iteration, output, stdout

I am Iterating over some counters in `C` to print the results on a single line separated like this `012, 013, 014, etc...`

My code comes to an end based on some conditions and it's being corrected by a bot.

how can i stop printing the `,`  after the last value of my code.
the idea s to get a 3 digit number with only unique digits and in ascending order
ending with `789`;

My function goes as follows:

```
void my_print_comb(void){
   for(int i = 47; i++ < 57 ; ){
      for(int j = 48; j++ < 57 ; ){
         for(int k = 49; k++ < 57 ; ){
             if( i != j && i != k && j != k){
                while( i < j && j < k){
                char a = i, b = j, c = k;
                my_putchar(a);
                my_putchar(b);
                my_putchar(c);
                my_putchar(',');
                my_putchar(' ');
                break;
                }
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: By modifying code not to print the `, ` after the last value of your code. Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Maybe, don't print the comma for the first number. Then after that print a comma before the number.

Comment: The option I usually choose is to print the delimiter before each token except for the first one.

Comment: Printing a comma before each item except the first works even if you don't know how many items you are going to print beforehand.

Comment: `for(int i = 47; i++ < 57 ; ){` This is usually not how to write a `for` loop. `for (int i = 48; i <= 57; i++) {` is preferred as it is more clear what exactly it does.

Comment: Also, `while (condition) {...break;}` can be replaced with `if (condition) {...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print one of the elements without the comma. Either print the first one and then iterate through the rest of the array and print each element with a `,`  in front of it; or print all the elements except the last one with a `,`  after each one, then print the last one. I like the first approach more.

Since you did not show any code I'm just going to give an example.

```c
void pretty_print_ints(const int *array, size_t count)
{
    // Nothing to do.
    if (count == 0 || array == NULL) return;

    // Print the first element, without a `,` after it.
    printf("%d", array[0]);

    // If there are more elements in the list, print them all, but add a `, ` separator.
    for (size_t i = 1; i < count; i++) printf(", %d", array[i]);

    // Add a new line at the end.
    printf("\n");
}
```

It also works if we don't know how many elements we have to print. For example, instead of stopping when we printed `count` elements we could stop when we hit an element equal to `0`, the only thing we need to change is the stop condition. If we went the other way around (print `count - 1` elements with `printf("%d, ", array[i]);` we won't be able to handle this case).